# FileHelperAsyncEngine<T> - Set Default Delimiter?

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I'm using the `FileHelperAsyncEngine<T>` class (from the [FileHelpers NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FileHelpers/)) to stream a very large CSV file from an MVC application.

We have many different types of data that we will want to stream to CSV, and I am looking for a way to set a default delimiter, so as to avoid having to decorate my data classes with the `[DelimitedRecord(",")]` attribute.

I know I could use the `CsvEngine` class instead, but performance is critical and the async version is orders of magnitude faster.

Am I missing something or is not possible to set a default record delimiter?

Answer (score 1):

I guess anything is possible after all. It's ugly, but this version uses reflection to create a new proxy class with the attribute.

```
namespace FileHelpersConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class Record
        {
            public string Id;
            public string Name;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var type = typeof(Record);

            var defaultDelimiter = ",";

            var aName = type.Assembly.GetName();
            var ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(aName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            var mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(aName.Name);
            var tb = mb.DefineType(type.Name + "Proxy", TypeAttributes.Public, type);

            var attrCtorParams = new Type[] { typeof(string) };
            var attrCtorInfo = typeof(DelimitedRecordAttribute).GetConstructor(attrCtorParams);
            var attrBuilder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(attrCtorInfo, new object[] { defaultDelimiter });
            tb.SetCustomAttribute(attrBuilder);

            var newType = tb.CreateType();

            var engine = new FileHelperAsyncEngine(newType);
            //var options = engine.Options as DelimitedRecordOptions;
            //options.Delimiter = "|"; // you can still change delimiter if you need to

            string src = "abc,JohnDoe";
            using (engine.BeginReadString(src))
            {
                var enumerator = (engine as IEnumerable<object>).GetEnumerator();
                enumerator.MoveNext();

                var currentRecord = enumerator.Current as Record;
                Assert.AreEqual("abc", currentRecord.Id);
                Assert.AreEqual("JohnDoe", currentRecord.Name);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting approach and would probably work for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast engine.Options to a `DelimitedRecordOptions` and change the delimiter.  Like this:

```
public class Program
{
    [DelimitedRecord(",")] // you need to specify some delimiter, even if you change it later...
    public class Record
    {
        public string Id;
        public string Name;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = new FileHelperAsyncEngine<Record>();
        var options = engine.Options as DelimitedRecordOptions;
        options.Delimiter = "|"; // change the delimiter to vertical bar

        // test
        string src = "abc|JohnDoe";
        using (engine.BeginReadString(src))
        {
            var enumerator = (engine as IEnumerable<Record>).GetEnumerator();
            enumerator.MoveNext();
            Assert.AreEqual("abc", enumerator.Current.Id);
            Assert.AreEqual("JohnDoe", enumerator.Current.Name);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work if you remove the `[Delimitedrecord(",""]` attribute.

Comment: That's right, you need the `DelimitedRecord` attribute so the engine knows there is *some* delimiter. But then you can override it as shown.

Comment: If you read my question, I was specifically looking for a solution that doesn't require that attribute. The attribute does nothing aside from establishing the delimiter; it could be done just as easily in the constructor of the `FileHelperAsyncEngine<T>` class.

Comment: I see. FileHelpers still needs to know it's a `DelimitedRecord` to differentiate it from `FixedRecord` which has no delimiter. It's not very elegant, but you could create your class from a string with `ClassBuilder.ClassFromSourceFile()` and after adding the attribute to the source dynamically. Then you would use the non-generic `FileHelperAsyncEngine(Type type)` instead.